# Bind9 forwarded zones statistics

Tags: bind, metrics, statistics

Is it possible to get a statistics count for forwarded zones similar to other zone types?

I have the following definitions in my `named.conf.local` and am able to successfully make queries for both zones.

```
zone "transfer-bindtest.com" {
    type secondary;
    file "db.transfer-bindtest.com";
    masters { 10.20.10.5; };  # ns1 private IP
    zone-statistics yes;
};
zone "bindtest.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.20.10.5; };
};
```

However, after making a number of queries I can see query statistics for `transfer-bindtest.com` but NOT for `bindtest.com`. The only indication that the forwarded request was handled is that the total query count increases

I have looked through the list of statistics as defined in the ARM (section 4.4) which did not list anything related to forwarded queries. Additionally, I have searched to see if there was a plugin that had been developed that would provide this capability but have come up empty.